# cycling through values in a MS Access list box

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a list box that populates with different sets of data based on user selections.

How can I cycle through any given values that may be in the list box? Is this a `For Each` statement, or what?

Comment: Do not forget that you can have a multiselect list box and use the Selected property if space on the form becomes an issue.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do a `For` loop to examine each row in the listbox, and do *whatever* with the rows which are selected.  In this example, I display the second column from selected items in the *lstLocations* listbox.  (Column numbering starts with zero.)

```vb
Private Sub cmdShowSelections_Click()
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim strMsg As String

    With Me.lstLocations
        For lngRow = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(lngRow) Then
                strMsg = strMsg & ", " & .Column(1, lngRow)
            End If
        Next lngRow
    End With

    ' strip off leading comma and space
    If Len(strMsg) > 2 Then
        strMsg = Mid(strMsg, 3)
    End If
    MsgBox strMsg
End Sub
```

Note I assumed you want the selected items from the list box.  If you want *all* items, selected or not, you could use `.ItemData` as @DavidRelihan [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933167/77335).  However, in that case, you could get them from the listbox `.RowSource` instead.

Answer (score 27):

Here is how you iterate through the ListBox:

```
Dim i as Integer

For i = 0 to Me.ListBoxName.ListCount -1
   'Access each item with 
   'Me.ListBoxName.ItemData(i)
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

If working with a listbox in Access I like to capture the listbox recordset and loop through it. Perhaps because I find DAO recordset objects easy to work with.

I'd do something like:

```
Dim Rst as DAO.Recordset
Set Rst = lbxYourListboxObj.Recordset
'test to assure that there are records
If Rst.EOF then
     'some error handling
end if
'I'm just paranoid so I always do this
Rst.MoveFirst
'iterate through list
Do Until Rst.EOF
    'do something for each record
    'it is nice and convenient to be able to reference the field names directly too!
    debug.print Rst!Field1.name,Rst!Field1.value
    Rst.MoveNext
Loop
```