# Checking the last element in list in ms access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have problem with check the last element in list in ms access and put the last value to label. I have used a loop to realize this:

```
Private Sub lstAbgänge_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

i = 0
r = 0

Do Until Me.lstAbgänge.Column(0, i) = Null
   i = i + 1
   r = Me.lstAbgänge.Column(0, i)
   If r = Null Then Exit Do
Loop

'Me.lblVorgangNr.Caption = Me.lstAbgänge.Column(0, i - 1)

End Sub
```

My problem is that loop is neverending, I have tried end this loop by condition "Me.lstAbgänge.Column(0, i) = Null" and next by "If r = Null Then Exit Do" but in both cases it doesn't work. When it has value Null loop is still working.

[View of list in form](http://imageshack.us/a/img600/8531/dbpj.png)
[Debbuging](http://imageshack.us/a/img17/7583/pbp3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub lstAbgänge_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim i as Integer
    For i = 0 to Me.lstAbgänge.ListCount - 1
        Debug.Print Me.lstAbgänge.Column(0, i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

You need to use the ListCount property to iterate to the end of the list.

See this post: [cycling through values in a MS Access list box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933113/access-2007-cycling-through-values-in-a-list-box-vba)