# Loop to get value using multiple parameters

Tags: vba, excel

**The Goal:**

My program currently calculates values for heating and cooling costs for a single month of use. Now, I am trying to allow users to enter multiple months of use.

**What I Have Done so Far:**

I created functions (along with the Userform and output sheet) that calculate the heating and cooling costs for 2 different situations (4 functions total). Below is the code for one of them. The only change between the different functions is the line that has 2 stars next to it. Those are 4 separate drop downs in the VBA userform (there may have been a more efficent way to do that, but alas here we are).

```
Function CoolingCostS1(month As String, sqft As Single, ElecAUC As Single, Days As Single) As Single

'variable declaeration
Dim cost As Single

Select Case Main.ddRegion.value 'Case statement for region value

    Case "South"

       **Select Case Main.ddS1Cooling.value** 

            Case "Chill Water System"

                Set chillWater = New clsMonth 'create new object for CWS system

                    With chillWater 'assign calculated values

                        .January = 0.7136 / 20
                        .February = 0.6755 / 20
                        .March = 0.6528 / 20
                        .April = 0.7773 / 20
                        .May = 0.8213 / 20
                        .June = 0.8715 / 20
                        .July = 0.9 / 20
                        .August = 1.0243 / 20
                        .September = 1.0516 / 20
                        .October = 0.8514 / 20
                        .November = 0.7095 / 20
                        .December = 0.6994 / 20

                        cost = .ValueFor(month) * sqft * ElecAUC * Days

                    End With

            Case "Direct Expansion"

                Set DX = New clsMonth

                    With DX

                        .January = 0.577 / 20
                        .February = 0.553 / 20
                        .March = 0.516 / 20
                        .April = 0.611 / 20
                        .May = 0.703 / 20
                        .June = 0.74 / 20
                        .July = 0.801 / 20
                        .August = 0.834 / 20
                        .September = 0.9333 / 20
                        .October = 0.686 / 20
                        .November = 0.597 / 20
                        .December = 0.4907 / 20

                        cost = .ValueFor(month) * sqft * ElecAUC * Days
                    End With
        End Select

    Case "North"

        Select Case Main.ddS1Cooling.value 

            Case "Chill Water System"

                Set chillWater = New clsMonth 'create new object for CWS system

                    With chillWater 'assign calculated values

                        .January = 0.775 / 20
                        .February = 0.845 / 20
                        .March = 0.699 / 20
                        .April = 0.722 / 20
                        .May = 0.751 / 20
                        .June = 0.1 / 20
                        .July = 0.9 / 20
                        .August = 0.95 / 20
                        .September = 0.946 / 20
                        .October = 0.749 / 20
                        .November = 0.739 / 20
                        .December = 0.75 / 20

                        cost = .ValueFor(month) * sqft * ElecAUC * Days

                    End With

            Case "Direct Expansion"

                Set DX = New clsMonth

                    With DX

                        .January = 0.536 / 20
                        .February = 0.52 / 20
                        .March = 0.49 / 20
                        .April = 0.482 / 20
                        .May = 0.511 / 20
                        .June = 0.5 / 20
                        .July = 0.5 / 20
                        .August = 0.461 / 20
                        .September = 543 / 20
                        .October = 0.521 / 20
                        .November = 0.497 / 20
                        .December = 0.531 / 20

                        cost = .ValueFor(month) * sqft * ElecAUC * Days
                    End With
        End Select

End Select

CoolingCostS1 = cost

End Function
```

As you can see, these functions only accept single months. The userform has an option for multiple months and when selected it displays check boxes, one for each month.

When the simulate button is clicked, the below code is executed:

```
Private Sub bSimulate_Click() 'logic to calculate simulation values

'''''''''''variable decleration'''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim s1Sqft As Single, s2Sqft As Single, s1ElecAUC As Single, s2ElecAUC As Single, s1HeatAUC As Single, s2HeatAUC As Single, Days As Single

'''''''''''conditional if and logic'''''''''''''''''''''

If IsNumeric(Me.txtS2elec.value) = True And IsNumeric(Me.txtS2NG.value) = True And IsNumeric(Me.txtS2sqft.value) = True And Me.ddS2cooling.ListIndex > -1 And Me.ddS2Heating.ListIndex > -1 Then

   **case for unselected using prior information**
   **case for selected using new information**

   'variable assignment

    s1Sqft = txtS1sqft.value 'system 1
    s1ElecAUC = txtS1elec.value
    s1HeatAUC = Me.txtS1NG.value

    s2Sqft = txtS2sqft.value 'system 2
    s2ElecAUC = txtS2elec.value
    s2HeatAUC = txtS2NG.value

    Days = txtUseDays.value 'usage page

   'resets cells back to white
    Me.txtS2elec.BackColor = vbWhite
    Me.txtS2NG.BackColor = vbWhite
    Me.txtS2sqft.BackColor = vbWhite


   'System one output
    Cells(13, 3).value = Days
    Cells(14, 3).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(CoolingCostS1(Me.ddMonthOfUse.value, s1Sqft, s1ElecAUC, Days) / s1ElecAUC, 0) & " KWH"
    Cells(14, 5).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(CoolingCostS1(Me.ddMonthOfUse.value, s1Sqft, s1ElecAUC, Days), 0)
    Cells(15, 3).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((HeatingCostS1(Me.ddMonthOfUse.value, s1Sqft, s1HeatAUC, Days) / s1HeatAUC), 0) & " " & Me.ddHeatingUtility.value
    Cells(15, 5).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(HeatingCostS1(Me.ddMonthOfUse.value, s1Sqft, s1HeatAUC, Days), 0)

   'System two output
    Cells(21, 3).value = Days
    Cells(22, 3).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(CoolingCostS2(Me.ddMonthOfUse.value, s2Sqft, s2ElecAUC, Days) / s2ElecAUC, 0) & " KWH"
    Cells(22, 5).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(CoolingCostS2(Me.ddMonthOfUse.value, s2Sqft, s2ElecAUC, Days), 0)
    Cells(23, 3).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((HeatingCostS2(Me.ddMonthOfUse.value, s2Sqft, s2HeatAUC, Days) / s2HeatAUC), 0) & " " & Me.ddHeatingUtility.value
    Cells(23, 5).value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(HeatingCostS2(Me.ddMonthOfUse.value, s2Sqft, s2HeatAUC, Days), 0)

   'System one information output
    Cells(12, 9).value = Me.ddS1Cooling.value
    Cells(13, 9).value = Me.ddS1Heating.value
    Cells(14, 9).value = Me.txtS1sqft.value

   'System two information output
    Cells(20, 9).value = Me.ddS2cooling.value
    Cells(21, 9).value = Me.ddS2Heating.value
    Cells(22, 9).value = Me.txtS2sqft.value

Else

    HighlightBadCells2 'checks for incorrect cell input values
    MsgBox "Please check the highlighted cells"
    GoTo CleanFail

End If

Main.Hide

CleanFail:
End Sub
```

Where the two stars are, that was me brainstorming the possibility of doing two cases -one for multiple months being selected and for not.

Stack wont let me upload pictures yet, so I cant show you the userform.

**The Problem:**

I am having trouble trying to figure out the most efficient way to get the total cost over the multiple months that are selected. I have some ideas bouncing around but can't seem to get them out. Every time I start brainstorming I end up with either lots and lots of code or tons of separate functions or something that just seems absurd for the task. I figured I could use the existing functions, but I don't know how to do that when they select the multiple months.

Thanks in advance for your help. If anything is unclear, please let me know. That made sense to me but may be a mess for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right something like the following would suffice without creating new formulas for multiple selection:

```
Cells(22, 3).value = 0
Cells(23, 3).value = 0
For Each month in Me.ddMonthOfUse
    Cells(22, 3).value = Cells(22, 3).value + Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(CoolingCostS1(month.value, s1Sqft, s1ElecAUC, Days) / s1ElecAUC, 0) & " KWH"
    Cells(23, 3).value = Cells(23, 3).value + Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((HeatingCostS1(month.value, s2Sqft, s2HeatAUC, Days) / s2HeatAUC), 0) & " " & Me.ddHeatingUtility.value
Next month
```

Comment: Is there a way to apply that to the selected months from the userform? If I understand correctly, this would do it for every month in the data type.

Comment: Is ddMonthOfUse a listbox? If so I'll update the answer following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2933240/3218398