# MS Access Multiple value from a FORM into table as a Single Line

Tags: database, vba, forms, ms-access, multivalue

To avoid Multiple Value fields, I need some help to configure the "multi-select"  option of a FORM within MS Access to a SINGLE line/field.

Example:

[image]

And in the Table it should come out like one single line/field

Example

[image]

Is this even possible? if Show can someone help me?

Comment: Have a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933113/cycling-through-values-in-a-ms-access-list-box. It cycles through the list items, and appends the selected items to a single string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along these lines

```
Dim l As Long
Dim s As String

For l = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(l) Then
        s = s & Me.ListBox1.List(l) & ","
    End If
Next l

s = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
Debug.Print s
```